# How can I extract multiple 7zip archives to folders with the same names in Linux?

Tags: linux, 7-zip, extract

I have about 300 7zip archives, each with several files in them, and no directory structure inside.

I need to extract all these archives to folders that match the respective archive.

Example:

`foo.7z`
`bar.7z`

Extract contents of `foo.7z` to `/foo/`
Extract contents of `bar.7z` to `/bar/`

---

I tried this script:

`find . -name "*.7z" -type f| xargs -I {} 7z x -o{} {}`

But it resulted in:

```
can not open output file ./foo.7z/file.bin
Skipping    file.bin
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @platinums Pretty hard to use context menus on a non-graphical operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to create a directory with the same name as the file. That cannot work: There can't be two directory entries with the same name.

One way to fix this is to use `basename` to strip the `.7z` extension from the files and create the directories without the `.7z` suffix.

Like:

```
for archive in *.7z; do 7z x -o"`basename \"$archive\" .7z`" "$archive"; done
```

Comment: When I try that I get "there is no such archive".

Comment: Did you have any spaces in the archive names? I have fixed the command in the answer to properly handle filenames that contain whitespace.

Comment: Ah, yes that was it. Thanks! Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

To extract multiple *.7z files in the same directory with a single command, this will extract them all to separate directories named the same as the 7z archives without the `.7z`.

```
7za x -o* -y *.7z
```

Comment: See also this: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/output_dir.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.7z; do
    directory=${file/%.7z/}
    if mkdir ${directory}; then
        ( cd ${directory}; 7z x ../${file} )
    else
        echo "Unable to create directory ${directory} for archive ${file}" 1>&2
    fi
done
```

The way this works is first iterating through all the `*.7z` files using the `file` variable.  Once it grabs a filename, it uses bash string manipulation to strip the `.7z` off the end, and make a new variable, `directory`, out of that.

It will then try to create the directory, and, if it can, it will open up a subshell, go into that directory, and extract the 7zip archive.

If it was not able to create that directory, a message is sent to standard error.

I use a subshell so as to not have to worry about losing track of where I am with changes to the working directory.

The most abstruse part of this is this line:

directory=${file/%.7z/}

This is the aforementioned bash string manipulation, which will look for `.7z` at the end of a string, and if present, replace it with nothing.  If I wanted to replace it with, say, `.zip`, I could use `${file/%.7z/.zip}`.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain what this code does, how to run it, and how it addresses the problem?  Cautious readers are wary of unexplained code, and it's [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because it doesn't teach the solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @fixer1234, I have expanded upon my answer as you have requested.